# Ajax request error when changepage

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

guys. I have a juerymobile multi-page, and I have a button in `#page-index`, when click it, will send a ajax request to server, and changepage to `#page-column`, It run will in PC, but when i deploy the multi-page in phonegap, the button click can just run only twice, code is below:

```
function test()
{
    $.mobile.changePage('#page_column'); 
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://192.168.168.120:8090/fcmobile/getTest",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) { 
        alert(data.content);
    });
}
```

I found if I remove `$.mobile.changePage('#page_column');`, the ajax request can be run well any times. but when I add the `changePage` code, it only can be run twice, in third time, ajax request can't even be send. Dose anybody know reason?

Comment: I found the reason, the ajax should be set "async: false"

Answer (score 0):

AJAX is made to be asynchronous, so no need to set `async` to `false` to get it working. Use events instead.

For example:

```
function test () {
    $.ajax({
        'url': "http://192.168.168.120:8090/fcmobile/getTest",
        'dataType': 'json',
        'success': function (json_data) {
            $(document).trigger('test_json_data_loaded');

            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

$(document).on('test_json_data_loaded', function () {
    $.mobile.changePage('#page_column');
});
```

When you set `async` to `false`, you're basically making it so that every time this AJAX request is made, the user will have to wait until all the data is fully loaded before the application/website can do/execute anything else...not good.